# Why does my overlay not work on img hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to get my Img's to zoom and produce an overlay with text on my img hover. The text and zoom is currently working but the overlay doesn't. What am I missing in my code?

My first thought was maybe the overlay was hidden behind a value in z-index. When the value was changed the results did not change.

I've tried moving HTML and CSS around to see if this would help. No change in results.

Keep in mind that frame 1 and frame 2 are the ones I'm currently trying to focus on.

Thanks!

```css
.box-wrap {
    display: table;
    margin: 60px;
}

.zoom {
    position: relative;
}

.box-content h1{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 27%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

/* OVERLAY */

.zoom .overlay {
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
    opacity: 0;
}

.zoom:hover .overlay {
    z-index: 4;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

/* END OVERLAY */

/* TEXT */

.zoom h1{
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.zoom:hover h1 {
    pointer-events: none;
    visibility: visible;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    z-index: 3;
}

/* END TEXT */

/* ZOOM EFFECT */

.zoom img {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    transition: 6s;
    transform: scale(1.0);
}

.zoom img:hover {
    transition: 6s;
    transform: scale(2.0);
}

.frame {
    float: left;
    height: 500px;
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.frame img {
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
}

/* START BOX 2 */

.frame2 {
    float: right;
    height: 500px;
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.frame2 img {
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
}

/* END BOX 2 */

/* START BOX 3*/

.frame3 {
    float: left;
    height:300px;
    width: 25%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.frame3 img {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
}

/* END BOX 3 */

/* START BOX 4 */

.frame4 {
    object-fit: cover;
    float: right;
    height:300px;
    width: 25%;
    overflow: hidden;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.frame4 img {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
}

/* END OF BOX4 */

/* START BOX 5 */

.frame5 {
    float: left;
    height:300px;
    width: 25%;
    overflow: hidden;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.frame5 img {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
}

/* END OF BOX5 */

/* START BOX 6 */

.frame6 {
    float: right;
    height:300px;
    width: 25%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.frame6 img {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-wrap">

<div class="frame zoom">
<div class="box-content">
<h1>SKULL</h1>
<img src="img/skull.jpg" alt="#">
<span class="overlay"></span>
</div>
</div>

<div class="frame2 zoom">
<div class="box-content">
<h1>SWIRL</h1>
<img src="img/liquify.jpg" alt="#">
<div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="frame3 zoom">
<div class="box-content">
<h1>SWIRL</h1>
<img src="img/chief.jpg" alt="#">
</div>
</div>

<div class="frame4 zoom">
<div class="box-content">
<h1>SWIRL</h1>
<img src="img/vect.png" alt="#">
</div>
</div>

<div class="frame5 zoom">
<div class="box-content">
<h1>SWIRL</h1>
<img src="img/sun.jpg" alt="#">
</div>
</div>

<div class="frame6 zoom">
<div class="box-content">
<h1>SWIRL</h1>
<img src="img/card.jpg" alt="#">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to set the overlay width and height.

```
.zoom .overlay {
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100%; //define here
    height: 100% //define here
}
```

Other usual way to do that is using the :after pseudo element like:

```
.zoom:after {
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100%; //define here
    height: 100% //define here
}
```

This way you don't need to create a .overlay div

Comment: Unfortunately, even when changing the CSS to this nothing changes. There must be something in my code that is interfering with the overlay?

Comment: why this reply receive a -1 o.O, put the top and left properties to 0 like this: width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

Comment: The overlay works now but the zoom no longer works, any chance you'd know how to get them to both work? Idk why it has received a downvote?

Comment: the problem is that when the overlay appears, you cant hover the img anymore and the css for the zoom consist in a img hover, change the img hover part to: .zoom:hover img{
    transition: 6s;
    transform: scale(2.0);
}

Comment: Thank you very much Wolgan! You fixed my problem!